# GTK C - Passing multiple variables using g_signal_connect

Tags: c, gtk

So, I'm trying to achieve the following:

The user is choosing file, and path to that file is saved in variable filename. After choosing file user is selecting by checkbox which chmod want to set.

I have something like this:

```
g_signal_connect (ux, "toggled",G_CALLBACK(user_read_only), (gpointer *)ux);
```

and function user_read_only:

```
void user_read_only(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer *data)
{
   if (gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(data))){
       int stat;
       stat = chmod(filename, S_IRUSR);
       printf("Added Read attribute to user in file: %s\n", filename);
   } else {
      printf("No Read attribute to user in file: %s\n", filename);
   }
}
```

My question is: How I can pass filename to my callback function? When i try:

```
g_signal_connect (ux, "toggled",G_CALLBACK(user_read_only), (gpointer *)ux,filename);
```

I got error that I can pass only 1 variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That data parameter of gpointer type is for you to pass whatever type of data you want to pass onto your callback.

```
g_signal_connect (ux, "toggled",G_CALLBACK(user_read_only), (gpointer *)filename);
```

Should do the trick. You do not need to pass your GTK instance (ux) as data. You also need to change the function as:

```
void user_read_only(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer *data)
{
   if (gtk_toggle_button_get_active(GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON(widget))){
       int stat;
       stat = chmod(data, S_IRUSR);
       printf("Added Read attribute to user in file: %s\n", (char *)data);
   } else {
      printf("No Read attribute to user in file: %s\n", (char *)data);
   }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately no :( I need to check in function that ux is toggled or not and filename is second paremter to pass. Even if I'd pass only filename I got:
`format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type`

Comment: You already pass the ux in the first parameter (as widget), and you need to cast  (char *)filename when calling printf assuming the format warning you pointed out is treated as an error in your build system.

Comment: Thanks to that I've now less errors and filename is calling good. Now I've got error:
`s8.c: In function ‘main’:
s8.c:49:1: warning: ‘GtkStock’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
 dialog = gtk_file_chooser_dialog_new ("Open File",NULL,GTK_FILE_CHOOSER_ACTION_OPEN,GTK_STOCK_CANCEL,GTK_RESPONSE_CANCEL,GTK_STOCK_OPEN,GTK_RESPONSE_ACCEPT,NULL);
 ^
s8.c:49:1: warning: ‘GtkStock’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
s8.c:78:29: error: ‘GTK_CAN_FOCUS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  GTK_WIDGET_UNSET_FLAGS(ur, GTK_CAN_FOCUS);
                             ^
`

Comment: This error is unrelated to your question here. It is better practice to ask it as a new question.

Comment: Even, when this error show when I changed calling ux to widget?

Comment: Yes, assuming you've made the changes as shown in the last edit. The compiler error is irrelevant with your question. Cheers!